# Loading different blades for different routes in Laravel-VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

The application that I'm trying to build is Single Page Application (SPA).
My actual intention is load different blades for "/superadmin/*" routes and other routes like "/home".

Both templates have different styles and so I had created two blades, one for **superadmin** and one for other **users**.

So in **web.php** I've used to below code to load different blades for each route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {
    if ($any == 'superadmin' || $any == 'verify-email') {
        return View::make('superadmin');
    } else {
        return View::make('index');
    }
});
```

Also I have used the **layout-broker** package to switch between the layouts. This is my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <LayoutBroker :layouts="layouts" :current="$route.meta.layout" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import LayoutBroker from "vue-layout-broker";
import FrontendLayout from "./layouts/Frontend.vue";
import SuperadminLayout from "./layouts/Superadmin.vue";
import SuperadminLoginLayout from "./layouts/SaLoginLayout.vue";
import ErrorLayout from "./layouts/Error";

const layouts = {
  FrontendLayout,
  SuperadminLoginLayout,
  SuperadminLayout,
  ErrorLayout
};

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    LayoutBroker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      layouts
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

So I've specified which layout needs to be loaded for each route in **router.js**.

```
{ path: '/home', name: 'home', component: Home, meta: { layout: 'FrontendLayout', superadmin: false } },
{ path: '/superadmin', name: 'superadmin.login', meta: { layout: 'SuperadminLoginLayout' }, component: saLogin },
```

And this works and actually switches the layout as per routes.

But when it switches, at first the whole page css will be broken. After refreshing, the page css will be fine. Later I found out that while switching between the routes, the view/blade doesn't change (according to code in web.php) and that was what causing the issue. The view/blade doesn't change unless the page is reloaded. 
Well it was obvious,but how can I tackle this issue?

Currently I'm using the below code in **App.vue** that change css according to layout But there is a bit flickery feeling while browsing through pages.

```
<div v-if="$route.meta.layout === 'FrontendLayout'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</div>
<div v-else>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin-assets/assets/css/style.css" />
</div>
```

I'm looking for suggestions.